# AntiForgery cookie in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-webpages, antiforgerytoken

I wanted to implement [this solution](http://richiban.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/) to handle antiforgery in ajax requests. I know there are other solutions but this is the one I like most.

The problem is I have to deal with System.Web.Webpages 1.0 so I cannot make use of AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName in my code.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                string cookieName = AntiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(context.Request.ApplicationPath);
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null
                    ? antiForgeryCookie.Value
                    : null;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
                    .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I retrieve (programmatically) the cookie name set by the antiforgery system in Mvc3? I suspect the AntiForgery.Validate part will also be a problem but I'll handle that before. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The actual cookie name always starts from `"__RequestVerificationToken"` with some suffix. So you can find the cookie like this:

```
private static string FindCookieValueByName(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    return request.Cookies
        .Cast<string>()
        .Where(cn => cn.StartsWith("__RequestVerificationToken", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .Select(cn => request.Cookies[cn].Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```